# How to delete a record using inner join on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have 3 tables

Table A :

```
| id_A | Data ... |
```

Table B :

```
| id_B | Data ... |
```

Join A_B

```
| id_A | id_B |
```

Those tables are an example of my situation. Well, I am trying to delete many records from Join A_B depending on many conditions like the name of A is X and name of B is Y.

When I execute a SELECT it works, but with DELETE It doesn't.

This is my resquest:

```
DELETE A_B FROM A 
INNER JOIN A_B 
  ON (A.ID = A_B.A_ID) 
INNER JOIN B 
  ON (B.ID = A_B.B_ID) 
WHERE B.NAME IN ('X', 'Y') 
AND A.NAME = 'Z';
```

It says :

```
Erreur SQL : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: You want to DELETE FROM, not DELETE x FROM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only one From table is allowed when performing a Delete.
try

```
DELETE FROM A_B 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A 
  INNER JOIN B ON (B.ID = A_B.B_ID) 
  WHERE A.ID = A_B.A_ID
  AND B.NAME IN ('X', 'Y') 
  AND A.NAME = 'Z');
```

reference [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/delete.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
delete from A
where A.ID in
    (
    select A_ID
    from A_B
    inner join B
      on B.ID = A_B.B_ID
    where B.NAME in (...)
    )
and A.NAME = 'Z'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

```
merge into A
using (select * from A_B inner join B on (B.ID = A_B.B_ID) where B.NAME IN ('X', 'Y')) d
on (d.A_ID = A.ID)
when matched then delete where A.NAME = 'Z';
```